# How to use switch statement within a reduce method?

Tags: javascript

I want to resolve a problem (from https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures-projects/cash-register/). 
I ended up with a switch statement within a reduce method but it doesn't work like I explain it in the code. 
I just want to know why that doesn't work, not if there are other better ways to resolve this entire problem.

```
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) { 
// price refer to a purchase price, cash to the money given by a client, cid to the cash-in-drawer.

// With the method below, I want to convert the cid nested array into a single value in dollar.
  let register = cid.reduce( (sum, curr) => {
    switch (curr[0]) {
      case "PENNY" : 
        sum += curr[1] * 0.01; 
        break;
      // I would continue with case "NICKEL" etc. but the switch statement doesn't work.
      default: console.log("Unexpected currency unit");
    }
    },0)

    console.log(register);
} 

checkCashRegister(19.5, 20, [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.1], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90], ["FIVE", 55], ["TEN", 20], ["TWENTY", 60], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]]);
```

I expect the output 0.0101 but the actual output of "console.log(register)" is:

```
    Unexpected currency unit
    Unexpected currency unit
    Unexpected currency unit
    Unexpected currency unit
    Unexpected currency unit
    Unexpected currency unit
    Unexpected currency unit
    Unexpected currency unit
```

Comment: You never `return` anything from your reduce callback. So, in `case "PENNY"` nothing happens. You get all the other longs.

Comment: You mus return something inside reduce function

Comment: first of all, you need to iterate from the lagest unit to the smallest, in this case `reduceRight` would fit. then you need to take the value, which is the sum of the denominations and not the count of it. thant means, you need no `switch` statement, but to check if the amount is enough to get the change for this unit. never the less, you missed to stat5e the wanted result. is it an array with denominations and sum? or the rest of the cash?

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for your comment ! (And sorry for the time you lost for my bad mistake...)

Comment: Should I edit my question to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array.reduce requires you to return a value. Your switch statment is fine. I added `return sum;` to the end of your reduce function.

```
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) { 
// price refer to a purchase price, cash to the money given by a client, cid to the cash-in-drawer.

// With the method below, I want to convert the cid nested array into a single value in dollar.
  let register = cid.reduce( (sum, curr) => {
    switch (curr[0]) {
      case "PENNY" : 
        sum += curr[1] * 0.01; 
        break;
      // I would continue with case "NICKEL" etc. but the switch statement doesn't work.
      default: console.log("Unexpected currency unit");
    }
    return sum;
  },0)

  console.log(register);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

You do have some work to do in order to answer the question you linked, but I'm sure you'll get there. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That works. I knew I was probably doing a ridiculous mistake but I really appreciate your indulgence.